# Where to put facebook SDK in Magento folder

Tags: php, magento, facebook-php-sdk

I am learning Magento and try to create a module can connect with Facebook account via their Facebook ID.

Can you tell me where to put the SDK libary of facebook to whịch folder of magento and how can I config that libary

Answer (score 0):

You have to put that file in `lib` folder

**Eg:**

`lib/facebook/yourfile.php`

to get that file

```
require_once('facebook/yourfile.php')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the Facebook SDK folder where you want (eg in a `vendor/` directory at root), you just need to `require_once '/path/to/sdk/folder/autoload.php';` somewhere in your code.